# meaning in context of the word qualify

Tags: meaning-in-context

My husband stated, "we will both qualify for medicare in 2018" does this mean we do not qualify until that year? Or does it mean: as he thinks that by 2018 we will both qualify? He will in 2017 and I do not until 2018.

Otherwise I think he should have said we will both have qualified in 2018

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of knowing without context, because potentially, all three interpretations are correct.

My husband stated "we will both qualify for medicare in 2018" can mean the following:

- He alone qualifies now, but you will both qualify in 2018
- Neither of you qualify now, but you will both qualify in 2018.
- You both qualify now, and you both will still qualify in 2018.

There's no clause at the beginning of the sentence to narrow it down, so it really depends on the context of the sentence as a whole.